# Ray tune samples more than one value for the same model in multi-agent environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, hyperparameters, ray, multi-agent, rllib

So I have this weird behavior of ray tune that I can't make sense of.

What I'm trying to do:

- I have setup a custom rllib multi-agent env with two agents
- Both agents have different observation and action spaces
- Both should be trained with PPO but with a different config since I'm using custom Pytorch Models for them as well

You can see my configuration code below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ray.init()

    policies = {
        "pol_1": (
            None,
            obs_space_a,
            act_space_a
            {
                "model": {
                    "custom_model": "model_a",
                    "custom_model_config": {
                        "hidden_layer_size": 64,
                        "num_hidden_layers": 2,
                        "activation": "leaky_relu",
                    },
                },
            },
        ),
        "pol_2": (
            None,
            obs_space_b,
            act_space_a,
            {
                "model": {
                    "custom_model": "attacker_model",
                    "custom_model_config": {
                        "hidden_layer_size": tune.choice([64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]),
                        "num_hidden_layers": 2,
                    },
                },
            },
        ),
    }

    config = (
        AlgorithmConfig()
        .environment("concurrent_env", env_config={"num_agents": 2})
        .training(train_batch_size=1024, lr=1e-3, gamma=0.99)
        .framework("torch")
        .rollouts(num_rollout_workers=1, rollout_fragment_length="auto")
        .multi_agent(
            policies=policies,
            policy_mapping_fn=(
                lambda agent_id, episode, worker, **kw: f"pol_{agent_id}"
            ),
            policies_to_train=["pol_1", "pol_2"],
        )
    )

    results = tune.Tuner(
        "PPO",
        param_space=config.to_dict(),
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            stop={"training_iteration": 10000},
            callbacks=[AttackerRewardCallback()],
            #verbose=1,
        ),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(num_samples=1),
    ).fit()
```

As you can see I'd like to perform a hyperparameter optimization for my second agent.
The weird thing is: The hidden_layer_size seems to get sampled two times as you can see in this picture.
[image]

Of course only one can be used but there seems to be something wrong with my config.

I would expect that ...custom_model_config/hidden_layer_size only shows up one time.

If I run the analysis and print the chosen hidden_layer_size everytime the forward() function is called then it seems that only the first one is used anyways.